# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: hibernate, jboss6.x

I am using hibernate, jboss6.0.final and I am getting following exception:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tablename"
  Detail: Key (pkey)=(11929) already exists.
2011-07-18 06:28:04,373 ERROR [org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener] (http-69.89.2.245-8080-1) Could not synchronize database state with session: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94) [:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) [
```

I have excluded the jta.jar from hibernate-core.jar in my pom.xml. 
What is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The record you're trying to insert already exists. You need to use `update` or `saveOrUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is because you insert already persisted bean.